# how to detect a laptop hibernate/resume(close lid,open) in osx from a bash script

Tags: bash, osx, suspend

This is a follow on question to

[how to trap a suspend a resume from a bash script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11498/how-to-trap-a-suspend-a-resume-from-a-bash-script)

How do you a trap the event that occurs when you close the lid and later reopen it from a bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98995/run-script-on-suspend-resume-in-mac-os-x) asks a very similar thing, just not bash-specific. The accepted answer states to try a program called [Sleepwatcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/) for which the source is available.

From reading the source it seems like this program uses the apple-specific [`IORegisterForSystemPower` function](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1340/_index.html) which allows the small C-daemon to be notified by the system before the syetm goes to sleep and after it wakes back up.

There is no generic ACPI daemon on Mac OS X that I know of.